# Bazel run specify multiline command

Tags: linux, build, command-line-interface, bazel

Hello I am using [bazel](https://www.bazel.build/) for my project.

I always used backslash(\) to specify long commands in Linux.

I was trying the same bazel but it didn't worked

```
bazel build //mypackage:query_count -- \
--input="/path/to/input.json" \
--output="/path/to/output/json"
```

When I remove the backslash and keep them on one line the build succeeds

```
bazel build //mypackage:query_count -- --input="/path/to/input.json" --output="/path/to/output/json"
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong, looking into the error it looks like bazel is treating `--input="/path/to/input.json"` as a seprate target?

Comment: be sure there is no white space trailing after any of your `"\"` chars? Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

`--input="/path/to/input.json"` and `--output="/path/to/output/json"` are not flags for `bazel build` (to build the executable). I believe you're using them as runtime flags for the underlying executable `//mypackage:query_count`.

You probably want to use `bazel run` here:

```
bazel run //mypackage:query_count -- \
  --input="/path/to/input.json" \
  --output="/path/to/output/json"
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything after `--` is interpreted as target patterns:

https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/command-line-reference.html

```
bazel [<startup options>] <command> [<args>] -- [<target patterns>]
```

Though as Jin says above, `--input` and `--output` are not command line flags to bazel, so it's not clear what you're trying to do (unless you're just using those as dummy placeholder names for flags).

`--` behaves differently for `bazel run`: bazel interprets everything after `--` as arguments to the binary to run, see https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/user-manual.html#run